# If a cell value is equal or less than a number, then the resulting value will be in a particular cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

If cell C rows is between the numbers 0 - 3.9, cell D rows would input the number 7. If cell C rows are 4 - 7.9, it would input 10 on cell D rows. If cell C rows are 8 - 14.9 it would input 15 on cell D rows.

I was thinking it would be similar to:

```
=IF(C1>0-3.9,”7”,””)
```

Comment: `=CHOOSE(MATCH(C1,{0,4,8}),7,7.9,15)`

Comment: ^^ Or maybe `=INDEX({7,10,15},MATCH(C1,{0,4,8}))`. Btw, Excel or GS? They are very different despite they look similar.

Comment: Google Sheets is not Excel. Which of the two are you *actually* using? Please only use appropriate tags, to ensure an appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. That was much better and exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C1, {0,7;4,10;8,15}, 2, 0))
```